# Modify variable names which starts with a number in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset

I want to modify a name of a column, for instance from "2nd_Row" to "_2nd_Row", I tried to use the 'Rename' option, but is not working.

Can I do it into a SAS Program, or should I do it manually?

Thank you!

Comment: Back up to the step before you import the data. Add the following option and reimport data. `options validvarname=v7;` SAS should import with better names.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable names are actually "2nd_row"?  Or is it possible that's just a label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for name-literial.

```
rename '2nd_row'n = _2nd_row;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to find the documentation